# Included files & database connections

Tags: php, mysql

My php function does not recognize a variable defined in another php file that is included in within the same file.  dbconnect.php makes a database connect.  add_user.php has the add_user function which uses that database connection $dbco.  I get an error message saying that $dbco is not defined for this function call: `mysql_select_db("luxcal", $dbco);`  This must be something very obvious, but I don't know what is happening.

dbconnect.php

---

```
<?php
    $dbco = mysql_connect("localhost","myuser","mypassword");
    if (!$dbco)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
?>
```

add_user.php

---

```
<?php include("dbconnect.php"); ?>

<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function add_user($username, $email, $password_text, $copasswd_text) {

    $password = md5($password_text);
    $copasswd = md5($password_text);
    $privPost = 1; // 3: max.
    $privSedit = 0;

    mysql_select_db("luxcal", $dbco);

    $q_add_user = "INSERT INTO users (`user_name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES ( '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."', '$password' )";
    $r_add_user = mysql_query($q_add_user);

    return;
}

echo add_user(trim($_REQUEST['uname']), trim($_REQUEST['uemail']), trim($_REQUEST['upass']), trim($_REQUEST['cpass']));

?>
```

Comment: `mmowebdb` is not your real DB password, right? Also, you didn't pass $dbco into your function. You also need to salt your password. And you shouldn't use $_REQUEST you should use whatever method you specifically used to send the info like $_POST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `$dbco` is not available in the function `add_user` because it is not in the [variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) of the function.

You can access it by adding `global $dbco;` inside the `add_user` function to make it available, or you can use `$GLOBALS['dbco']` instead.

Try:

```
function add_user($username, $email, $password_text, $copasswd_text) {
    global $dbco;
    // rest of code...
}
```

Variables defined outside of functions are not available inside the function unless you pass them in or use `global`.  Similarly, a variable defined in a function is not available outside the function (and is freed when the function returns).

Answer (score 2):

Try doing a Singleton database class instead. In your case you can end up with many different database connections which is bad.

Something like this (taken and edited from: http://www.matthewelliston.com/php-singleton-database-class/ )

```
class Database {

    private static $instance;
    private $connection;

    private function __construct(){
        $this->connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","pw"); // or whatever connection you use
    }
    public static function getInstance(){
        if(empty(self::$instance)){
            try{
                self::$instance = new Database();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public function query($query, $args){ 
        ... //general query function
    }
}
```

You can then get a Database-instance by calling

```
$db = Database::getInstance();
//and do
$db.query("INSERT INTO ...");
```